# Conflict Hibernate and JBoss

Tags: hibernate, maven, jboss

I'm having issue to solve some dependencies conflict.

I have developed an application that is working on my local JBoss Dev Studio with JBoss EAP 6.1+ as Server using Hibernate 4.2.18.Final.
However this same application fails when I deploy it on our server - JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA.

I'm getting these error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.lionco.hibernate.HibernateUtil

and

> org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProviderInjector

It seems to be related to dependencies conflict with maybe hibernate.logging but I cannot find any information about it.

My current Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lionco</groupId>
    <artifactId>Bus</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Bus</name>
    <description>Bus</description>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dvdme</groupId>
            <artifactId>ForecastIOLib</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
            <artifactId>soap-builder</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
            <artifactId>soap-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
            <artifactId>soap-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>reficio</id>
            <url>http://repo.reficio.org/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate comes bundled with JBoss, so `hibernate-core` dependency should be scope provided.

Not so sure about `hibernate-c3p0`.. I would try leaving the compile scope and see what happens

Comment: I change the scope of hibernate-core but still it is not working and I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed my issue. It was a conflict between different version of hibernate-logging (or hibernate-commons-logging).

On eclipse it was using the correct files but my jar was containing oldest version of some dependencies which were conflicting.

I fixed the issue by deleted the previous jar on my project folder.